# Unwanted line breaks in PDF generated from XSL-FO?

Tags: html, xml, pdf, xslt, xsl-fo

I'm converting some HTML to a PDF using XSLT. I'm getting some unwanted line breaks, and I'm not sure why.

Here is the HTML source:

```
<li><strong>must</strong> only work in the occupation and for 
    the sponsor with the most recently approved nomination for
    the holder <strong>unless</strong> the visa holder's
    occupation is specified on a relevant instrument;
</li>
```

and here is what it looks like in a browser:

[image]

Here is some of the XSLT:

```
<xsl:template match="condition/div">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="div|p|ul|li|a|ol|strong"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="li" mode="bullet">
    <fo:list-item>
            Unicode Bullet Character
            <fo:list-item-label end-indent="label-end()">
                <fo:block>
                    &#x2022;
                </fo:block>
            </fo:list-item-label>
            <fo:list-item-body start-indent="body-start()">
                <fo:block font-size="8pt" padding-bottom="2mm" padding-top="1mm">
                    <xsl:apply-templates />
                </fo:block>
            </fo:list-item-body>
    </fo:list-item>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="strong">
    <fo:block font-weight="bold">       
        <xsl:value-of select="." />    
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>
```

...and here is what the output looks like:

[image]

As you can see, unwanted line breaks appear after the `<strong>` tags. Any ideas how to stop this from happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want [`fo:inline`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslfo20/#fo_inline) (like `span` in HTML) here rather than [`fo:block`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslfo20/#fo_block) (like `div` in HTML).

Change

```
<xsl:template match="strong">
    <fo:block font-weight="bold">       
        <xsl:value-of select="." />    
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>
```

to

```
<xsl:template match="strong">
    <fo:inline font-weight="bold">       
        <xsl:value-of select="." />    
    </fo:inline>
</xsl:template>
```

to eliminate the line breaks after `strong`.

Comment: I love Stackoverflow and I love kjhughes. :)